# Multipart forms from C# client

Tags: c#, http, multipartform-data

I am trying to fill a form in a php application from a C# client (Outlook addin). I used Fiddler to see the original request from within the php application and the form is transmitted as a multipart/form. Unfortunately .Net does not come with native support for this type of forms (WebClient has only a method for uploading a file).
Does anybody know a library or has some code to achieve this? I want to post different values and additionally (but only sometimes) a file.

Thanks for your help,
Sebastian

Comment: This works like a charm [www.briangrinstead.com/blog](http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/multipart-form-post-in-c)

Comment: If you don't mind a small library dependency, [Flurl](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/113) makes this about as simple as it gets. [Disclaimer: I'm the author]

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is cut and pasted from some sample code I wrote, hopefully it should give the basics. It only supports File data and form-data at the moment.

```
public class PostData
{

    private List<PostDataParam> m_Params;

    public List<PostDataParam> Params
    {
        get { return m_Params; }
        set { m_Params = value; }
    }

    public PostData()
    {
        m_Params = new List<PostDataParam>();

        // Add sample param
        m_Params.Add(new PostDataParam("email", "MyEmail", PostDataParamType.Field));
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the parameters array formatted for multi-part/form data
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string GetPostData()
    {
        // Get boundary, default is --AaB03x
        string boundary = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ContentBoundary"].ToString();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PostDataParam p in m_Params)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(boundary);

            if (p.Type == PostDataParamType.File)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Content-Disposition: file; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"", p.Name, p.FileName));
                sb.AppendLine("Content-Type: text/plain");
                sb.AppendLine();
                sb.AppendLine(p.Value);                 
            }
            else
            {
                sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"", p.Name));
                sb.AppendLine();
                sb.AppendLine(p.Value);
            }
        }

        sb.AppendLine(boundary);

        return sb.ToString();           
    }
}

public enum PostDataParamType
{
    Field,
    File
}

public class PostDataParam
{


    public PostDataParam(string name, string value, PostDataParamType type)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
        Type = type;
    }

    public string Name;
    public string FileName;
    public string Value;
    public PostDataParamType Type;
}
```

To send the data you then need to:

```
HttpWebRequest oRequest = null;
oRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(oURL.URL);
oRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";                       
oRequest.Method = "POST";
PostData pData = new PostData();

byte[] buffer = encoding.GetBytes(pData.GetPostData());

// Set content length of our data
oRequest.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

// Dump our buffered postdata to the stream, booyah
oStream = oRequest.GetRequestStream();
oStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
oStream.Close();

// get the response
oResponse = (HttpWebResponse)oRequest.GetResponse();
```

Hope thats clear, i've cut and pasted from a few sources to get that tidier.

Comment: I don't think this works, the boundary is not defined in the Content-Type and there must be added to the left "--" of the boundary for each one that is written and "--" to the right of the last one.
Don't ask me how this magical "--" appears, they are implied in the official documentation:
https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2
If you don't like magical requirements as me, you are going to have a hard time making this work as I did.

Comment: This code definitely works for scenarios I have used it in. However I see that while I'm defining the full boundary to be send in the post data, I have not specified adding this onto the overall content header as the boundary delimiter. As for the magic number, this is determined by the client to ensure it is unique and will not appear inside the content anywhere, see here for more detail: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html

Answer (score 72):

Thanks for the answers, everybody!  I recently had to get this to work, and used your suggestions heavily.  However, there were a couple of tricky parts that did not work as expected, mostly having to do with actually including the file (which was an important part of the question).  There are a lot of answers here already, but I think this may be useful to someone in the future (I could not find many clear examples of this online).  I [wrote a blog post](http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/multipart-form-post-in-c) that explains it a little more.

Basically, I first tried to pass in the file data as a UTF8 encoded string, but I was having problems with encoding files (it worked fine for a plain text file, but when uploading a Word Document, for example, if I tried to save the file that was passed through to the posted form using Request.Files[0].SaveAs(), opening the file in Word did not work properly.  I found that if you write the file data directly using a Stream (rather than a StringBuilder), it worked as expected.  Also, I made a couple of modifications that made it easier for me to understand.

By the way, the [Multipart Forms Request for Comments](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) and the [W3C Recommendation for mulitpart/form-data](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) are a couple of useful resources in case anyone needs a reference for the specification.

I changed the WebHelpers class to be a bit smaller and have simpler interfaces, it is now called `FormUpload`.  If you pass a `FormUpload.FileParameter` you can pass the byte[] contents along with a file name and content type, and if you pass a string, it will treat it as a standard name/value combination.

**Here is the FormUpload class:**

```
// Implements multipart/form-data POST in C# http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt
// http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/multipart-form-post-in-c
public static class FormUpload
{
    private static readonly Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    public static HttpWebResponse MultipartFormDataPost(string postUrl, string userAgent, Dictionary<string, object> postParameters)
    {
        string formDataBoundary = String.Format("----------{0:N}", Guid.NewGuid());
        string contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + formDataBoundary;

        byte[] formData = GetMultipartFormData(postParameters, formDataBoundary);

        return PostForm(postUrl, userAgent, contentType, formData);
    }
    private static HttpWebResponse PostForm(string postUrl, string userAgent, string contentType, byte[] formData)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(postUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("request is not a http request");
        }

        // Set up the request properties.
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = contentType;
        request.UserAgent = userAgent;
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.ContentLength = formData.Length;

        // You could add authentication here as well if needed:
        // request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        // request.AuthenticationLevel = System.Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequested;
        // request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("username" + ":" + "password")));

        // Send the form data to the request.
        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(formData, 0, formData.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
        }

        return request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    }

    private static byte[] GetMultipartFormData(Dictionary<string, object> postParameters, string boundary)
    {
        Stream formDataStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        bool needsCLRF = false;

        foreach (var param in postParameters)
        {
            // Thanks to feedback from commenters, add a CRLF to allow multiple parameters to be added.
            // Skip it on the first parameter, add it to subsequent parameters.
            if (needsCLRF)
                formDataStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes("\r\n"), 0, encoding.GetByteCount("\r\n"));

            needsCLRF = true;

            if (param.Value is FileParameter)
            {
                FileParameter fileToUpload = (FileParameter)param.Value;

                // Add just the first part of this param, since we will write the file data directly to the Stream
                string header = string.Format("--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"; filename=\"{2}\";\r\nContent-Type: {3}\r\n\r\n",
                    boundary,
                    param.Key,
                    fileToUpload.FileName ?? param.Key,
                    fileToUpload.ContentType ?? "application/octet-stream");

                formDataStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(header), 0, encoding.GetByteCount(header));

                // Write the file data directly to the Stream, rather than serializing it to a string.
                formDataStream.Write(fileToUpload.File, 0, fileToUpload.File.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                string postData = string.Format("--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"\r\n\r\n{2}",
                    boundary,
                    param.Key,
                    param.Value);
                formDataStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(postData), 0, encoding.GetByteCount(postData));
            }
        }

        // Add the end of the request.  Start with a newline
        string footer = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n";
        formDataStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(footer), 0, encoding.GetByteCount(footer));

        // Dump the Stream into a byte[]
        formDataStream.Position = 0;
        byte[] formData = new byte[formDataStream.Length];
        formDataStream.Read(formData, 0, formData.Length);
        formDataStream.Close();

        return formData;
    }

    public class FileParameter
    {
        public byte[] File { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string ContentType { get; set; }
        public FileParameter(byte[] file) : this(file, null) { }
        public FileParameter(byte[] file, string filename) : this(file, filename, null) { }
        public FileParameter(byte[] file, string filename, string contenttype)
        {
            File = file;
            FileName = filename;
            ContentType = contenttype;
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is the calling code, which uploads a file and a few normal post parameters:**

```
// Read file data
FileStream fs = new FileStream("c:\\people.doc", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
byte[] data = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
fs.Close();

// Generate post objects
Dictionary<string, object> postParameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
postParameters.Add("filename", "People.doc");
postParameters.Add("fileformat", "doc");
postParameters.Add("file", new FormUpload.FileParameter(data, "People.doc", "application/msword"));

// Create request and receive response
string postURL = "http://localhost";
string userAgent = "Someone";
HttpWebResponse webResponse = FormUpload.MultipartFormDataPost(postURL, userAgent, postParameters);

// Process response
StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
string fullResponse = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
webResponse.Close();
Response.Write(fullResponse);
```

Comment: Spectacular.  I modified to show progress, support PUT requests and use my own cookiecontainer but this was a ton of help to get me on my way.

Comment: Excellent baseline.  I made minor adjustments to accommodate for our needs, but definitely a HUGE help in multi-part boundary posting.  Significantly simplified my work.  Thanks

Comment: #Brian I exactly followed your code But its not Working :(

Comment: so the file is read to the memory before sending, what if it's a big file

Answer (score 35):

With .NET 4.5 you currently could use System.Net.Http namespace. Below the example for uploading single file using multipart form data.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace HttpClientTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            content.Add(new StreamContent(File.Open("../../Image1.png", FileMode.Open)), "Image", "Image.png");
            content.Add(new StringContent("Place string content here"), "Content-Id in the HTTP"); 
            var result = client.PostAsync("https://hostname/api/Account/UploadAvatar", content);
            Console.WriteLine(result.Result.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if am getting details of a multipart form in the URL , here am asking about files like a pdf

Comment: you can add more form-data content (like an Id) with content.Add(new StringContent("1"),"MyId");

Answer (score 13):

Building on dnolans example, this is the version I could actually get to work (there were some errors with the boundary, encoding wasn't set) :-)

To send the data:

```
HttpWebRequest oRequest = null;
oRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://you.url.here");
oRequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + PostData.boundary;
oRequest.Method = "POST";
PostData pData = new PostData();
Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
Stream oStream = null;

/* ... set the parameters, read files, etc. IE:
   pData.Params.Add(new PostDataParam("email", "example@example.com", PostDataParamType.Field));
   pData.Params.Add(new PostDataParam("fileupload", "filename.txt", "filecontents" PostDataParamType.File));
*/

byte[] buffer = encoding.GetBytes(pData.GetPostData());

oRequest.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

oStream = oRequest.GetRequestStream();
oStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
oStream.Close();

HttpWebResponse oResponse = (HttpWebResponse)oRequest.GetResponse();
```

The PostData class should look like:

```
public class PostData
{
    // Change this if you need to, not necessary
    public static string boundary = "AaB03x";

    private List<PostDataParam> m_Params;

    public List<PostDataParam> Params
    {
        get { return m_Params; }
        set { m_Params = value; }
    }

    public PostData()
    {
        m_Params = new List<PostDataParam>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the parameters array formatted for multi-part/form data
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string GetPostData()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (PostDataParam p in m_Params)
        {
            sb.AppendLine("--" + boundary);

            if (p.Type == PostDataParamType.File)
            {
                sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Content-Disposition: file; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"", p.Name, p.FileName));
                sb.AppendLine("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
                sb.AppendLine();
                sb.AppendLine(p.Value);
            }
            else
            {
                sb.AppendLine(string.Format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"", p.Name));
                sb.AppendLine();
                sb.AppendLine(p.Value);
            }
        }

        sb.AppendLine("--" + boundary + "--");

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

public enum PostDataParamType
{
    Field,
    File
}

public class PostDataParam
{
    public PostDataParam(string name, string value, PostDataParamType type)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
        Type = type;
    }

    public PostDataParam(string name, string filename, string value, PostDataParamType type)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
        FileName = filename;
        Type = type;
    }

    public string Name;
    public string FileName;
    public string Value;
    public PostDataParamType Type;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In the version of .NET I am using you also have to do this:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
```

If you don't, the `HttpWebRequest` class will automatically add the `Expect:100-continue` request header which fouls everything up.

Also I learned the hard way that you have to have the right number of dashes.  whatever you say is the "boundary" in the `Content-Type` header has to be preceded by two dashes

```
--THEBOUNDARY
```

and at the end

```
--THEBOUNDARY--
```

exactly as it does in the example code.  If your boundary is a lot of dashes followed by a number then this mistake won't be obvious by looking at the http request in a proxy server

Comment: THIS IS IMPORTANT! Thank you so much for mentioning this, I never would have considered it otherwise and it was the only thing messing me up!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the code, it saved me a lot of time (including the Except100 error!).

Anyway, I found a bug in the code, here:

```
formDataStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(postData), 0, postData.Length);
```

In case your POST data is utf-16, postData.Length, will return the number of characters and not the number of bytes. This will truncate the data being posted (for example, if you have 2 chars that are encoded as utf-16, they take 4 bytes, but postData.Length will say it takes 2 bytes, and you loose the 2 final bytes of the posted data).

Solution - replace that line with:

```
byte[] aPostData=encoding.GetBytes(postData);
formDataStream.Write(aPostData, 0, aPostData.Length);
```

Using this, the length is calculated by the size of the byte[], not the string size.

Comment: encoding.GetByteCount(postData) may be a better option if you only need to determine byte count

Answer (score 2):

A little optimization of the class before.
In this version the files are not totally loaded into memory.

Security advice: a check for the boundary is missing, if the file contains the bounday it will crash.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public static class FormUpload
    {
        private static string NewDataBoundary()
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            string formDataBoundary = "";
            while (formDataBoundary.Length < 15)
            {
                formDataBoundary = formDataBoundary + rnd.Next();
            }
            formDataBoundary = formDataBoundary.Substring(0, 15);
            formDataBoundary = "-----------------------------" + formDataBoundary;
            return formDataBoundary;
        }

        public static HttpWebResponse MultipartFormDataPost(string postUrl, IEnumerable<Cookie> cookies, Dictionary<string, string> postParameters)
        {
            string boundary = NewDataBoundary();

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(postUrl);

            // Set up the request properties
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
            request.UserAgent = "PhasDocAgent 1.0";
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

            foreach (var cookie in cookies)
            {
                request.CookieContainer.Add(cookie);
            }

            #region WRITING STREAM
            using (Stream formDataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                foreach (var param in postParameters)
                {
                    if (param.Value.StartsWith("file://"))
                    {
                        string filepath = param.Value.Substring(7);

                        // Add just the first part of this param, since we will write the file data directly to the Stream
                        string header = string.Format("--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"; filename=\"{2}\";\r\nContent-Type: {3}\r\n\r\n",
                            boundary,
                            param.Key,
                            Path.GetFileName(filepath) ?? param.Key,
                            MimeTypes.GetMime(filepath));

                        formDataStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header), 0, header.Length);

                        // Write the file data directly to the Stream, rather than serializing it to a string.

                        byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];

                        FileStream fs = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Open);

                        for (int i = 0; i < fs.Length; )
                        {
                            int k = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            if (k > 0)
                            {
                                formDataStream.Write(buffer, 0, k);
                            }
                            i = i + k;
                        }
                        fs.Close();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        string postData = string.Format("--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"\r\n\r\n{2}\r\n",
                            boundary,
                            param.Key,
                            param.Value);
                        formDataStream.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData), 0, postData.Length);
                    }
                }
                // Add the end of the request
                byte[] footer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
                formDataStream.Write(footer, 0, footer.Length);
                request.ContentLength = formDataStream.Length;
                formDataStream.Close();
            }
            #endregion

            return request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to simulate a browser login to a website to get a login cookie, and the login form was multipart/form-data.

I took some clues from the other answers here, and then tried to get my own scenario working. It took a bit of frustrating trial and error before it worked right, but here is the code:

```
    public static class WebHelpers
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Post the data as a multipart form
        /// </summary>
       public static HttpWebResponse MultipartFormDataPost(string postUrl, string userAgent, Dictionary<string, string> values)
       {
           string formDataBoundary = "---------------------------" + WebHelpers.RandomHexDigits(12);
           string contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + formDataBoundary;

           string formData = WebHelpers.MakeMultipartForm(values, formDataBoundary);
           return WebHelpers.PostForm(postUrl, userAgent, contentType, formData);
       }

        /// <summary>
        /// Post a form
        /// </summary>
        public static HttpWebResponse PostForm(string postUrl, string userAgent, string contentType, string formData)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(postUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

            if (request == null)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("request is not a http request");
            }

            // Add these, as we're doing a POST
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = contentType;
            request.UserAgent = userAgent;
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

            // We need to count how many bytes we're sending. 
            byte[] postBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formData);
            request.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                // Push it out there
                requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
                requestStream.Close();
            }

            return request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generate random hex digits 
        /// </summary>
        public static string RandomHexDigits(int count)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                int digit = random.Next(16);
                result.AppendFormat("{0:x}", digit);
            }

            return result.ToString();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Turn the key and value pairs into a multipart form
        /// </summary>
        private static string MakeMultipartForm(Dictionary<string, string> values, string boundary)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var pair in values)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"\r\n\r\n{2}\r\n", boundary, pair.Key, pair.Value);
            }

            sb.AppendFormat("--{0}--\r\n", boundary);

            return sb.ToString();    
        }
    }
}
```

It doesn't handle file data, just form since that's all that I needed. I called like this:

```
    try
    {
        using (HttpWebResponse response = WebHelpers.MultipartFormDataPost(postUrl, UserAgentString, this.loginForm)) 
        {
            if (response != null)
            {
                Cookie loginCookie = response.Cookies["logincookie"];
                .....
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code which I'm using

```
    //This URL not exist, it's only an example.
    string url = "http://myBox.s3.amazonaws.com/";
    //Instantiate new CustomWebRequest class
    CustomWebRequest wr = new CustomWebRequest(url);
    //Set values for parameters
    wr.ParamsCollection.Add(new ParamsStruct("key", "${filename}"));
    wr.ParamsCollection.Add(new ParamsStruct("acl", "public-read"));
    wr.ParamsCollection.Add(new ParamsStruct("success_action_redirect", "http://www.yahoo.com"));
    wr.ParamsCollection.Add(new ParamsStruct("x-amz-meta-uuid", "14365123651274"));
    wr.ParamsCollection.Add(new ParamsStruct("x-amz-meta-tag", ""));
    wr.ParamsCollection.Add(new ParamsStruct("AWSAccessKeyId", "zzzz"));            
    wr.ParamsCollection.Add(new ParamsStruct("Policy", "adsfadsf"));
    wr.ParamsCollection.Add(new ParamsStruct("Signature", "hH6lK6cA="));
    //For file type, send the inputstream of selected file
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"file.txt");
    wr.ParamsCollection.Add(new ParamsStruct("file", sr, ParamsStruct.ParamType.File, "file.txt"));

    wr.PostData();
```

from the following link I've downloaded the same code
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/multipart_request_C_.aspx

Any Help

Answer (score 0):

My implementation

```
/// <summary>
/// Sending file via multipart\form-data
/// </summary>
/// <param name="url">URL for send</param>
/// <param name="file">Local file path</param>
/// <param name="paramName">Request file param</param>
/// <param name="contentType">Content-Type file headr</param>
/// <param name="nvc">Additional post params</param>
private static string httpUploadFile(string url, string file, string paramName, string contentType, NameValueCollection nvc)
{
    //delimeter
    var boundary = "---------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");

    //creating request
    var wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    wr.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
    wr.Method = "POST";
    wr.KeepAlive = true;

    //sending request
    using(var requestStream = wr.GetRequestStream())
    {
        using (var requestWriter = new StreamWriter(requestStream, Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            //params
            const string formdataTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"\r\n\r\n{1}";
            foreach (string key in nvc.Keys)
            {
                requestWriter.Write(boundary);
                requestWriter.Write(String.Format(formdataTemplate, key, nvc[key]));
            }
            requestWriter.Write(boundary);

            //file header
            const string headerTemplate = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: {2}\r\n\r\n";
            requestWriter.Write(String.Format(headerTemplate, paramName, file, contentType));

            //file content
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                fileStream.CopyTo(requestStream);
            }

            requestWriter.Write("\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n");
        }
    }

    //reading response
    try
    {
        using (var wresp = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse())
        {
            if (wresp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                using (var responseStream = wresp.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    if (responseStream == null)
                        return null;
                    using (var responseReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                    {
                        return responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

            throw new ApplicationException("Error while upload files. Server status code: " + wresp.StatusCode.ToString());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException("Error while uploading file", ex);
    }
}
```