# How to use http post with proxy support in c#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

How to use http post with proxy support in c# and multipart  form data upload method

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[This post by Brian Grinstead](http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/multipart-form-post-in-c) explains how you can do just that.

For proxy support, you only need to pass a `Proxy` setting to `HttpWebRequest`. So, in the above example, you would change:

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(postUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
```

To:

```
string MyProxyHostString = "192.168.1.200";
int MyProxyPort = 8080;

HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(postUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Proxy = new WebProxy (MyProxyHostString, MyProxyPort);
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is it hard codes the proxy address/port into the compiled code.

Comment: That can easily be placed anywhere else. I put it in this way to explain the example better.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to configue a proxy then you can do so in the .config file:-

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true">
    <proxy proxyaddress="http://myproxyserver:8080" bypassonlocal="True"/>
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203811/how-to-submit-a-multipart-form-data-http-post-request-from-c) on form data posting.

Comment: http post?
webRequest ?
what atr you saying?

Comment: Sorry thought you we just asking about proxy support, however the largest part of the question is regarding multipart form data.

Comment: can i use proxy in some one ex. http://www.proxy4free.com/page1.html
to http post 189.80.133.186  8080 ??

Comment: Don't see why not, assuming you really want to expose your data to any Tom, Dick or Harry that might be running a free proxy server.

Comment: "Proxy support ?"  What exactly are you asking?  The answer describes how you specify a proxy server that classes in System.Net namespace will use.

Answer (score 1):

If the web request works fine in your localhost with default proxy 
and not working in your web server, then you have to set your
company's approved proxy and also whitelist the URL you are connecting to 
from your web application in the web server.

You can mention the proxy settings either in web.config or in code.

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true">
    <proxy proxyaddress="http://yourcompanyproxyserver:8080" bypassonlocal="True"/>
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

(or)

```
HttpWebRequest wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("URL");
wr.Proxy = new WebProxy("companyProxy",Portnumber);
wr.Method = "POST";
```