# How do I call httpwebrequest c# .net

Tags: c#, .net, proxy, httpwebrequest

I am trying to learn how to use proxies..

My main goal is to be able to input a proxy adress in a text box and use that input as an actual proxy adress for the webBrowser in c#

But first what I need to figure out is how do I call the httpwebrequest?

I was looking at this question and the answers below and I was trying to follow along but when ever I try to use the httpwebrequest it doesnt even pop up in intellisense.

Im refering to this line right here

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(postUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
```

[how to use http post with proxy support in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372519/how-to-use-http-post-with-proxy-support-in-c-sharp)

Comment: What url are you using?  You need are running webpage.

Comment: @jdweng I am trying to navigate to google by using this
webBrowser1.Navigate(urlBox.Text); im navigating the browser to what ever website i tell it to go to

Comment: It doesn't pop up in intellisense, but does it compile? If it doesn't compile, what error did you get?

Comment: HttpWebREquest doesnt exist in the current context

Comment: You probably have a bad url.  This works : HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(" h t t p : / / w w w . g o o g l e . c o m ") as HttpWebRequest; I added spaces so the posting didn't get changed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code in button click calls `HttpWebRequest` that redirects to google home page that you can get either XML or HTML and you can also redirects to page.

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.google.co.in");
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            //Get response as stream from httpwebresponse
            StreamReader resStream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            //Create instance for xml document
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            //Load response stream in to xml result
            xmlResult = resStream.ReadToEnd();
            //Load xmlResult variable value into xml documnet
            doc.LoadXml(xmlResult);
```

Please refer this image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH16C.png) and [snapshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0CWP.png)