# .Net - Use HttpClient to POST a file?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, httpclient, asp.net-web-api

I have a debug method that I'm trying to use to use to post multiple files to a local endpoint to simulate a series of uploads.

I have the following code:

```
var fi = new FIleInfo(....);
var form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
form.Add(new StreamContent(fi.OpenRead()), "file", fi.Name);
client.PostAsync(@"http://localhost:12372/TemplateManagement/Asset/Create", form);
```

that I want to post to a method with the following signature (asset comes from a custom binder but that's not important):

```
public JsonResult Create(HttpPostedFileBase file, DynamicBuilderAsset asset)
```

The post gets made ok but the file parameter is null. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try quoting the name and the filename:

```
form.Add(new StreamContent(fi.OpenRead()), "\"file\"", "\"" + fi.Name + "\"");
```

And the same is true if you are sending standard keys:

```
form.Add(new StringContent("some asset data"), "\"asset\"");
```

Comment: Took this long for me to get back to it but yes, this worked. Thanks Darin