# Wcf client won't connect to server(no packets out)

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-client

I have a strange issue on a server. Only on that server: it's a win 2008 R2. I can't figure It out.

If I launch a console(a simple wcf client) with a simple wcf call, even to a non existing remote endpoint/service,and wireshark capture activeted, I get no packet captured.

If I test that console in any other server/os(even another win server 2008 r2) it works(wireshark capture the outgoing packet).

Appearently there are no antivirus/firewall or anything blocking the request.

The wcf settings are not important for that test. I want only to see if any packet goes out with the Wcf call.

Notes:
Test as administrator.
Test with framework 4 and 4.5.
If I use http binding the console hangs after the call to the service(no packets out).
If I use https binding got an exception, something like "connection is not allowed"(no packets out).

It seems an OS related issue.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you running the app as an administrator? Also - what version of .NET are you targeting?

Comment: Sure, as administrator. Test with framework 4 and 4.5:same result.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but is the server blocked from the network or otherwise restricted in making calls?

Comment: No network restriction but still investigating