# How to capture WPF localhost traffic using Fiddler/RawCap/Wireshark?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, fiddler

I have a working WPF application running. It is pointing to my local IIS service. I'm trying to capture the traffic data and below are the ways i have tried so far but no luck.

1) fiddler

> try to add **localhost.fiddler** to the endpoint but not working. can't even see the service page by using browser.
>
> [image]
>
> Added the system.net in web.config OR machine.config and still not working.

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy>
    <proxy  proxyaddress="http://127.0.0.1:8888" />      
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

> I can see fiddler capturing https://localhost:8443/xxxx.svc if i browse it using chrome. Why I can't see the traffic when I run my WPF application?
>
> Below is my endpoint config
>
> [image]

2) RawCap

> I have enable the loopback interface in windows 10 and run rawcap
>   I get bunch of log from .pcap file and I'm not sure why is it capturing so many things....I can't find any related traffic log that coming from my WPF application
>   [image]

Below is the exception i get when hitting the service from my application

[image]

Can it be due to my local Certificate?

I have tried another approach which is using IISExpress which bypass the certificate using http://, but my fiddler still not capturing anything from my WPF application.

Comment: did you mean WCF?

Comment: Also, are you limited to using those tools? If not, there are a number of alternatives you can try in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215882/wcf-inspect-the-messages-being-sent-received?

Comment: @NPras as long as i'm able to monitor the packet size transfer from server - client. I'll take a look at the provided link.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to capture server trafic (from w3wp to distant REST service) using this on Windows 10:

Run IIS Pool at your own name.

Steps: 
IIS -> App Pool -> Your pool -> Advanced parameters -> Identity -> User Account
Enter your username / password of your local account.
*** Using "Microsoft account" of windows 8+, you need to enter your name like this: 
"MicrosoftAccount\myemail@mydomain.com" (Works on Win10 update 1511)
You may get a "keyset does not exist" error message.

And now, I can see all my client-server and server-server traffic!

Comment: Can you please enlighten me on the "Enter your username / password of your local account"?? I assume the Identity you mention here is under Process Model tab in AppPool's Advanced Settings.

Answer (score 0):

with fiddler, remove the proxy config and use http://machine/xxx in the wcf config files for the endpoint in IIS. This works...