# Monitor keep alive setting between UI and service web app

Tags: wcf

Our MVC application communicates via WCF with a services web app (also WCF).

Both apps (MVC & Services) use basic http by default, but we want to prevent server affinity. I made a custom binding that resembles the basichttp, but with settings 'keepAliveEnabled = false'.

The application works as before, but I want to verify if the keep alive is set to false between the UI and services.

How can this be done ?

(WireShark, Fiddler ??)

Comment: You can use any network monitor on the server for that. Look for the keep-alive request header in the requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

I checked this post on SO:

[How to use Fiddler to monitor WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629800/how-to-use-fiddler-to-monitor-wcf-service)

and replaced the localhost DEV client setting to my full computer name and I can track all the UI outbound calls now.