# Capture WCF client request with a proxy configuration

Tags: wcf, proxy, fiddler

I need to capture trafic with fiddler but in my config i need to specify a proxy to perform the connection my .config looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="asdClientTest.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.net>
   <defaultProxy  enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
      <proxy proxyaddress="http://zzzzz"></proxy>
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="ATEX">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="ATEX1">
          <security mode="Transport" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="ATEX2" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://zzzzzzzz"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ATEX" contract="WS.ConsultaATEX"
          name="ATEX" />      
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>  
</configuration>
```

but fiddler is not capturing nothing.
does anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [here](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/ChainToUpstreamProxy) you will find how to properly configure Fiddler to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is running locally you may be missing `bypassonlocal="False"` in the `<proxy>` tag. I took this information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629800/how-to-use-fiddler-to-monitor-wcf-service?rq=1).

Hope it helps!