# HttpClient does not work with Fiddler

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpclient, fiddler

I have gone through the forum and tried those techniques but still Fiddler is not able capture my traffic. Any help would help.

Following works with Fiddler, so my WebAPI server is working. My C# client returns OK.

```
http://localhost:49305/api/Employee/12345
```

.

Host file

```
 #localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
 #127.0.0.1       localhost
 #::1             localhost
```

.

```
    static async Task GoAny()
    {
        HttpClientHandler clntHand = new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
            Proxy = new WebProxy("http://localhost:8888", false),
            UseProxy = true,
            UseDefaultCredentials = false
        };

        HttpClient clnt = new HttpClient(clntHand)
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:49305")
        };

        clnt.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        clnt.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


        HttpResponseMessage resp = await clnt.GetAsync("api/Employee/12345");
        if (resp.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {

            string c = resp.Content.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure you don't have show "browser only" filter in Fiddler (look at bottom left corner of Fiddler window)...

Comment: I could not find setting saying 'browser only' by my filter tab is fully grayed out and nothing is checked there.  "Tool->Connections" says "Bypass Fiddler for URLs that start with" = "<-loopback>;"

Comment: Thanks Alexi..   Appending ".fiddler" to localhost solved it. That is "http://localhost.fiddler:49305".    Now Fiddler shows traffic flow.

Comment: You should post that as answer (and eventually accept it).

Comment: Further (official) detail: http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Observe-Traffic/Troubleshooting/NoTrafficToLocalhost

Comment: Saved my ass on something thank you!

Comment: So this was solved by an answer for [virtually the same question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31136258/1801588). Should we make it a proper answer here or close as a dupe?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I trace the HttpClient request using fiddler or any other tool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500299/how-can-i-trace-the-httpclient-request-using-fiddler-or-any-other-tool)

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue when using localhost.

Your url is `http://localhost:49305` and you need to change it to include `.fiddler` after localhost: `http://localhost.fiddler:49305`.

Once you have done this, the request from HttpClient should then appear in Fiddler.

Please see this SO question: [How can I trace the HttpClient request using fiddler or any other tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22500299/how-can-i-trace-the-httpclient-request-using-fiddler-or-any-other-tool)