# Uploading to Imageshack

Tags: c#, http, http-post, imageshack

Does anybody know how to upload to imageshack.us with C#? Two other threads here couldn't help:/
That's my piece of code. "PostParamCollection" is a library for sending HTTP Post. Lots of thanks for any help!

Im getting the error-message: "
Sorry, but we've detected that unexpected data is received. Required parameter 'fileupload' is missing or your post is not multipart/form-data

"

```
String imageshackurl = "http://www.imageshack.us/upload_api.php?";

                    PostParamCollection postParamCollection = new PostParamCollection();
                    postParamCollection.Add(new PostParam("key", imageshack_key));
                    postParamCollection.Add(new PostParam("Content-Disposition", "form-data"));
                    postParamCollection.Add(new PostParam("filename", "a.jpg"));
                    postParamCollection.Add(new PostParam("Content-Type", "image/png"));

                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(imageshackurl);
                    httpPost.doPost(postParamCollection);
                    String link = httpPost.responseStream;

                    WriteLog(link);
```

Comment: this should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3890754/c-using-httpwebrequest-to-post-data-upload-image-using-multipart-form-data

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be adding a *fileupload* parameter to your `postParamCollection`, which, I assume, would need to be of type `byte[]` and contain the file's contents.

I see that `PostParam` uses strings for its name and value, which is unsuitable for submitting binary data, such as an image file. Unfortunately, you will need to use a different method for posting the data to ImageShack. Take a look at the built-in .NET [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) class, which should allow you to do this.