# Uploading a byte array to a HTTP server

Tags: c#, arrays, upload, byte, httprequest

I would like to upload a byte array to a HTTP(S) server. I am aware that this can be done using the WebClient but I would like to send some POST arguments along with the byte array.

How can I do this with more fundemental classes like HTTPWebRequest? These are the conditions that the solution should meet:

- It should also work in HTTPS.
- It should not require the byte array to be written to a temporary file. What I mean is that I should be able to do everything right within the memory.

Also, if the solution requires something different to be done over the server side, it would be great if you also state that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx

Comment: @Jaroslav Jandek - What if I have other another data to send. Like sending the byte array and sending some other data.

Comment: Do you mean you want to simulate a multipart upload? Or could you sen te byte[] simply as a base-64 post argument?

Comment: Exactly, a multipart upload. I want to send the byte array and some other information at the same time.

Comment: @user418522: Read **RFC 2388** to see how the request stream should look (form-data, boundaries), stream the bytes in (textual data as UTF-8 encoded string) or simply find a library that will do it for you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219827/multipart-forms-from-c-client

Answer (score 2):

You should check this question:
[Multipart forms from C# client](https://stackoverflow.com/q/219827/213550)
especially this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/769093/213550

There is a lot of code, but the main idea is:

1. Set the Request's `ContentType` to the `multipart/form-data`
2. Add the boundary and the byte array to the Request's body
3. Get the Response.