# httpmultipart request for this webservice getdata code in c# with android

Tags: c#, android, web-services, httpclient, multipartentity

HI i have a webservice IIS with this code:

```
    // Implements multipart/form-data POST in C# http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt
// http://www.briangrinstead.com/blog/multipart-form-post-in-c
public static class FormUpload
{
    private static readonly Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    public static HttpWebResponse MultipartFormDataPost(string postUrl, string userAgent, Dictionary<string, object> postParameters)
    {
        string formDataBoundary = String.Format("----------{0:N}", Guid.NewGuid());
        string contentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + formDataBoundary;

        byte[] formData = GetMultipartFormData(postParameters, formDataBoundary);

        return PostForm(postUrl, userAgent, contentType, formData);
    }
    private static HttpWebResponse PostForm(string postUrl, string userAgent, string contentType, byte[] formData)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(postUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

        if (request == null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("request is not a http request");
        }

        // Set up the request properties.
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = contentType;
        request.UserAgent = userAgent;
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.ContentLength = formData.Length;

        // You could add authentication here as well if needed:
        // request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        // request.AuthenticationLevel = System.Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.MutualAuthRequested;
        // request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("username" + ":" + "password")));

        // Send the form data to the request.
        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(formData, 0, formData.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
        }

        return request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    }

    private static byte[] GetMultipartFormData(Dictionary<string, object> postParameters, string boundary)
    {
        Stream formDataStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        bool needsCLRF = false;

        foreach (var param in postParameters)
        {
            // Thanks to feedback from commenters, add a CRLF to allow multiple parameters to be added.
            // Skip it on the first parameter, add it to subsequent parameters.
            if (needsCLRF)
                formDataStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes("\r\n"), 0, encoding.GetByteCount("\r\n"));

            needsCLRF = true;

            if (param.Value is FileParameter)
            {
                FileParameter fileToUpload = (FileParameter)param.Value;

                // Add just the first part of this param, since we will write the file data directly to the Stream
                string header = string.Format("--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"; filename=\"{2}\";\r\nContent-Type: {3}\r\n\r\n",
                    boundary,
                    param.Key,
                    fileToUpload.FileName ?? param.Key,
                    fileToUpload.ContentType ?? "application/octet-stream");

                formDataStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(header), 0, encoding.GetByteCount(header));

                // Write the file data directly to the Stream, rather than serializing it to a string.
                formDataStream.Write(fileToUpload.File, 0, fileToUpload.File.Length);
            }
            else
            {
                string postData = string.Format("--{0}\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{1}\"\r\n\r\n{2}",
                    boundary,
                    param.Key,
                    param.Value);
                formDataStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(postData), 0, encoding.GetByteCount(postData));
            }
        }

        // Add the end of the request.  Start with a newline
        string footer = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--\r\n";
        formDataStream.Write(encoding.GetBytes(footer), 0, encoding.GetByteCount(footer));

        // Dump the Stream into a byte[]
        formDataStream.Position = 0;
        byte[] formData = new byte[formDataStream.Length];
        formDataStream.Read(formData, 0, formData.Length);
        formDataStream.Close();

        return formData;
    }

    public class FileParameter
    {
        public byte[] File { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string ContentType { get; set; }
        public FileParameter(byte[] file) : this(file, null) { }
        public FileParameter(byte[] file, string filename) : this(file, filename, null) { }
        public FileParameter(byte[] file, string filename, string contenttype)
        {
            File = file;
            FileName = filename;
            ContentType = contenttype;
        }
    }
}
```

Obtain from here: [Multipart forms from C# client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219827/multipart-forms-from-c-sharp-client)

But now, in mi android aplicattion i have this:

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            int timeoutConnection = 300000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
            int timeoutSocket = 300000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://172.21.1.87:9999/Service1.svc");
            ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(ficheroAEnviar, "prueba.jpg");
            MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();            
            postRequest.addHeader("Content-Type", " multipart/form-data");
            reqEntity.addPart("Dictionary", new FileBody(new File(fileUri.toString(), "application/zip")));
            reqEntity.addPart("boundary", new StringBody("envio"));
            postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String sResponse;
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            postRequest.getAllHeaders();

            while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                s = s.append(sResponse);
            }
            System.out.println("Response: " + s);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // handle exception here
            Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

But it return me Bad request 400 error. Can i use the c# code to upload a multipartentity file with android or a need to make any change in some code?

Anyone have a example en c# and android to make this? Is for uppload videos about 10 or 15 MB.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

dont use multipart entity instead use as here you define the bounderies it is easy
try it

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
 DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
DataInputStream inputStream = null;

   String pathToOurFile = "/data/file_to_send.mp3";
    String urlServer = "http://192.168.1.1/handle_upload.php";
  String lineEnd = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary =  "*****";

int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
byte[] buffer;
int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

try
{
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );

URL url = new URL(urlServer);
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

 // Allow Inputs & Outputs
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setUseCaches(false);

 // Enable POST method
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

  connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
  connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

 outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
   outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""+pathToOurFile       +"\"" + lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

 bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

// Read file
bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

while (bytesRead > 0)
 {
outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
}

outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

// Responses from the server (code and message)
serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

fileInputStream.close();
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
//Exception handling
}
```

courtesy rafel

Comment: But i need to use a webservice iis, this dont is for me, no?

Comment: multipart post is a common stuff there is no diff in iis nd Apache on that buddy

Comment: But how can i call a method UploadFile from http://172.21.1.87:9999/Service1.svc, SOAP¿

Comment: try giving it in url space might work 
i had an issue in posting an image to a php server with multi part post this cleared it now i am using an asp server there to i am able to do with it

Comment: sorry dude i don't handle asp here so its hard sry jst try a search but i think in your post also you are not using a soap envelope just posting directly

Comment: pls note in your code you are setting the mime type of an image to application/zip try changing that too

Comment: look at the buffer size (1*1024*1024)

Comment: Same result. I will try use multipart again

Comment: yap try that as i never had to post big images no probs occurred