# using catchoom in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest

i want to use catchoom in c# , but not able to find any sample
could any one please provide any sample code if have.

i have got this sample of curl

can some one covert this to c#

```
 curl -F "image=@CATask1-Correct.png" -F "token=sometoken" https://r.catchoom.com/v1/search
```

i tried to convert it like this

string url = "https://r.catchoom.com/v1/search";

```
       WebRequest myReq = WebRequest.Create(url);
       myReq.Headers["token"] = "sometoken";
       myReq.Headers["image"] = "imageurl";
       string username = "someid";
       string password = "pwd";
       string usernamePassword = username + ":" + password;
       CredentialCache mycache = new CredentialCache();
       mycache.Add(new Uri(url), "Basic", new NetworkCredential(username, password));
       myReq.Credentials = mycache;
       myReq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(usernamePassword)));

       WebResponse wr = myReq.GetResponse();
       Stream receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();
       StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
       string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

But throws error, 404 not found

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should encode the post parameters in form-multipart format, as described in the [W3C page](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2). [This answer shows how to encode in form-multipart format using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219827/multipart-forms-from-c-sharp-client)

Also, if you are using the Microsoft .NET Framework >= 4.5, you may use the HttpClient class as [this answer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16416601/c-sharp-httpclient-4-5-multipart-form-data-upload).

Hope this help you ;)