# Upload Video File From Harddisk to server RestSHARP

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am new to RestSharp, using C# WPF, i want to upload a video (mp4) file to server using PHP API and RestSharp.

```
var Client = new RestClient("https://www.XXXX.com/");
var Request = new RestRequest("FILE.php", Method.POST);
Request.AddParameter("uniqueID", DeviceID);
Request.AddParameter("POSTID", POSTID);
Request.AddParameter("outPutVideoPath", outPutVideoPath);
Request.AddParameter("accesstoken", "TOKEN");
```

This is not uploading file.

Comment: If you are _uploading_, where are you adding the file???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to upload a file using POST request via multipart uploading, then use this format

```
var client = new RestClient("https://www.xxxx.com/File.php");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; [boundary info]");
request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data",[multiparted data], 
ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: Thanks @MD , and i am sorry but can you just a single parameter to [multiparted data], so that i can have idea about that.

Comment: @EnhanceLabs please follow this question, you will get a proper idea,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219827/multipart-forms-from-c-sharp-client

Comment: Done bro. Thanks  :)